# Removing rows with redundant data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with pair of texts. Some data is redundant for different columns of the data frame.
For example, the screenshot of data frame is following:
[image: img]

| COLUMN_A | COLUMN_B |
| --- | --- |
| a | x |
| b | y |
| x | a |

Here row 0 has (a,x) and row 2 has (x,a), which is redundant in my case and has to be deleted. I am building a huge dataset for comparing the semantic similarity between two pairs of texts. At the moment, I want to compare each row with all of the other rows of the same data frame to remove duplicates.
How can I compare both columns of each row with all of the other rows?

Comment: This is row level duplicates regardless of column order? Or cell level duplicates? Like would row 0 `x a` and row 1 `x x` be considered duplicates since `x` already appears in the Frame or no only `a x` `x a` because both `a` and `x` appear in the row?

Comment: only row0 "a-x" and and row 2"x-a" are considered as duplicates

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
col_list = ['COULMN_A','COULMN_B']
df[col_list] = np.sort(df[col_list].to_numpy(),axis=1)
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset = col_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an auxiliary column to concatenate the text in the other columns and then drop everything you need.

Like this:

```
df['aux'] = df['COULMN_A'].str.cat(df['COULMN_B'])
df['aux'] = list(map(lambda x : ''.join(sorted(x)), df['aux']))
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['aux'], inplace=True)
df.drop(columns=['aux'],inplace=True)
```